# Must there exists a tour and cycle given that there exists a closed walk in a multigraph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

First of all some definitions: 
**multigraph**: a graph with edges that appear more than once and loops (a vertex v can be neighbors with itself).
**closed walk:** a sequence of edges not necessarily distinct s.t. the first and last vertex is the same. 
**tour:** a closed trail, where a trail is a walk with distinct edges. 
**cycle:** a trail where the only repeated vertex is the first/last vertex.
finally, with definitions out of the way, if there is a closed walk containing two vertices $u_1$ and $u_2$ in a multigraph $G=(V,E)$, must there be a tour and cycle containing $u_1$ and $u_2$?

I've previously proven that if there exists a walk between two vertices, then there must be a path between the two points. Since a path (no repeated vertices) is also a trail. This implies that there must a tour between the two vertices $u_1$ and $u_2$.
<s>Because we can simply add the edge $u_1u_2$ to the end of the path to get a tour. Thus this tour generated from a path will automatically be a cycle as well. Therefore there must be a tour AND cycle if there is a closed walk containing $u_1$ and $u_2$.</s> .
EDIT: I realized that I cannot simply add an edge. Does this mean that IF the edge $u_1u_2$ exists in the closed walk, then there is a tour and cycle, but if not, then there isn't? Thus there is not necessarily a tour and cycle containing $u_1$ and $u_2$
Is my logic correct or is there something I missed?

Comment: What happens if there are two vertices and a single edge between them? Is there a closed walk?

Comment: In that case, while there is a path/trail, there indeed isn't a closed walk. I realized you cannot simply "add" an edge like I stated in the question. I shall edit this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no "If exactly this edge exists" condition that tells you if $u_1$ and $u_2$ lie on a common tour or cycle.

There is a broader condition that does work, however, given by [Menger's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem#). The basic idea relevant here is this:

If there does not exist an edge $e$ such that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are disconnected in $G-e$, then there are $2$ edge-disjoint $u_1-u_2$ paths in $G$. The union of these two paths is a tour.
If there is no vertex $v$ such that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are disconnected in $G-v$, then there are $2$ vertex-disjoint $u_1-u_2$ paths in $G$, and the union of these paths is a cycle.

This theorem is very robust, and works for directed graphs, multigraphs and there are versions for edge-cuts and vertex cuts.